# Is there a function that returns "<br />" when in HTML and PHP_EOL when in CLI?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is there a function that returns HTML break, <br /> when in HTML and PHP_EOL when in CLI?

so that if I code something like:

echo "error is" . appropriateEOL();

will return the appropriate line break. I know how to code appropriateEOL(), I just wonder if there is a built in function.

I am using zf2.

Comment: Couldn't you use different templates for that purpose?

Comment: @sdfor Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing built-in to do what you're asking. But it would be trivial to set it up yourself.

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
   define("LINE_BREAK", PHP_EOL);
}
else {
   define("LINE_BREAK", "<br/>");
}
```

Now just use this `LINE_BREAK` constant.

Though it might be better to stick with non-html in your code and use `PHP_EOL`, and then run your output through `nl2br()` before displaying output in your HTML templates.

Comment: I agree you should stick with `PHP_EOL` and then use `nl2br()` in your html view.